# Android - Unit Testing of a Method in Activity

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, android

I have developed an app and currently working on writing Unit Tests for it.
The Problem is I have to write tests for the methods in the activities.So How should I do that?If it is simple Java We can create a Class Object (in which that method exists ) and can call that method.But hoe should we proceed here ? 
I did my part of research but didn't find any helpful resource.
Please share your ideas
PS:I have gone through the developer site and some others but not able to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start with the resources presented by Google in the Android Developer Pages: [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html). You will find an explanation for junit extensions which will allow to use various Android objects like Activities, Services, etc and create unit tests for them.